# Postfix transport based on source IP address (with or without relayhost)

Tags: centos, postfix, redhat, smtp

We have Postfix relay server running on centOS 7.4.

Restricted source IP address by mynetworks cidr

mynetworks = cidr:/etc/postfix/allowlist.cidr

Now, I like to configure, some of the source ip address range to be relay though our Anti Spam SMTP server (10.0.0.200) while some source IP addresses not require relayhost. Direct send out from postfix server.

For example

```
192.168.1.0/24 - relay through 10.0.0.200 port 25
192.168.2.0/24 - relay through 10.0.0.200 port 25
192.168.3.0/24 - relay through 10.0.0.200 port 25
192.168.10.0/24 - No need relay host
192.168.20.0/24 - No need relay host
```

How to configure this in postfix? Transport?